# Using standard jQuery events with SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

Is there some way to use the standard jQuery events with SlickGrid? For example.

```
grid = new Grid($("#myGrid"), data, columns, options);
grid.blur(function(){}); // this would be nice

// this will let me add jQuery events to the whole grid, but 
// I lose the cell position/data
$("#myGrid").blur(function(){});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

To elaborate, SlickGrid is not a jQuery plugin and does not extend jQuery in any way.  It is a separate component that uses jQuery under the hood.  It has explicitly defined events that you can subscribe to by setting event handlers on the grid instance.  While **some** of the "standard" events do apply to the DOM nodes generated by the grid, their use is discouraged.  The nodes are being created and removed by SlickGrid as you scroll, so you cannot rely on them staying the same or event being there.  Unless you have a good understanding of SlickGrid internals, it is best to stick with explicitly defined events.

Initially, I have considered changing SlickGrid to use jQuery events but I have decided against it.  While I have chosen to use jQuery as the framework for SlickGrid, there is no need to force the users to learn and use it as well.  This also gives me the flexibility to switch to another framework at a later time.

Comment: @maximus I'm sorry you feel that way.  Are you frustrated by the lack of specific events or by the mechanism through which they are implemented?

Comment: @tin don't get me wrong, I think it's a great plugin. I'm just frustrated that there isn't a specific event. (The onBlur would be really useful). I'm trying to implement a spreadsheet in jquery, so I want to do insert `=sum(` highlight some cells, and insert the cell addresses after the (. This seems to be the most promising of the jquery grids to do that. But, I can't see a way to do that with the current event system and the editor lock. Perhaps I should post another stackoverflow question?

Comment: @maximus:  I don't think you can do that using cell navigation since switching focus to another cell will commit your current cell edit and close the editor.  Could you describe the *exact* user interactions?

Comment: @tin I had suspected as much. The user interaction is very similar to excel. Click on a cell to activate it; enter =sum(, or whatever formula, the original cell address is saved, select the cell range (I assume that the original cell closes the editor), focus is returned to the original cell with the new cell range appended. i.e. `=sum(r1c1,r2c2)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think it makes sense to start another question, that way I can give points.

Comment: @tin here's the new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228091/excel-like-behavior-with-slickgrid

Answer (score 1):

You can always look into rendered code and apply .blur() to created container.